# Differences: 信息 vs 讯息?

Tags: translation, difference, etymology

What are the differences between:

信息 vs 讯息?

- Perhaps 信 is more related to the mailing?
- Perhaps 讯 is more related to the information?
- Perhaps 息 is related to the breathing?

Comment: I found 讯息 is used more in TWN than in mainland.  信息 is used more in mainland China.

Answer (score 3):

I originally thought the two are the same but after some research, I've reached the following conclusion:

> [信息](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E4%BF%A1%E6%81%AF) - information (in general)

Example:

大量信息 - a lot of information

毫无信息  - no information,

错误信息  - wrong information

科学信息 - scientific information

互通信息 - mutually sending information = sharing information

> [讯息](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E8%A8%8A%E6%81%AF) - message; news; information (specific)

> 讯息是一段独立的沟通内容，由传送者传达给一个或多个对象  - It is an independent piece of communication, which is communicated by the sender to one or more objects )

Example:

一段讯息 - a message

错误讯息  - wrong message

求救讯息 - help message (SOS is a message)

互通讯息 (mutually sending messages = communicating)

*A message is a piece of specific information, therefore 一段讯息(a message) is also **an** information*

- 信 (letter) contains information
- 讯 (message; news) e.g. 新闻快讯  (express news); 社区简讯 (Community newsletter)
- 息 (breath) gives a detectable sign = provides information