# What is the difference between 讯息 and 消息 and 信息?

Tags: difference

I'd like to know what is the most common word for a "message", like a SMS or just a message you receive on internet

Comment: Please see [this answer](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/42947/differences-%e4%bf%a1%e6%81%af-vs-%e8%ae%af%e6%81%af)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

|  | China | Taiwan |
| --- | --- | --- |
| text message | 短信 | 簡訊 |
| multimedia message | 彩信 | 多媒體訊息 |
| WeChat, common in China | 微信（消息 xiāoxi） | 微信（消息 xùnxí） |
| Line, common in Taiwan | Line（消息 xiāoxi） | Line（訊息 xùnxí） |
| iMessage | e.g., 我收到一条 iMessage（消息）和一条 WhatsApp（消息）。 | e.g., 我收到一條 iMessage （訊息）和一條 WhatsApp （訊息）。 |

The content in brackets can be omitted.